# Executar uma função PHP com o JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso chamar uma função do PHP através do JavaScript ao clicar em um elemento (evento `onclick`).

Fiz estas linhas básicas pra var se alguém pode ajudar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" onclick="funcaoJava()">Enviar</button>

<?php
    funcaoPHP () {
        echo "PHP EXECUTADO":
    }
?>

    <script>
        function funcaoJava(){
            // Chamar a função PHP
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O JS não tem nenhuma conexão com o PHP, exceto por Ajax.

Comment: Entendi. Então não há nenhuma possibilidade de fazer isso sem usar o ajax?

Comment: Não tem como porque o PHP roda no servidor e o JS no navegador.

Comment: É um pecado nomear uma função com `funcaoJava` no JavaScript!

Answer (score 4):

> "*- chamar uma função no PHP através do JavaScript*"

Você não pode fazer isso! O PHP é uma linguagem que roda no servidor (back-end) enquanto (no seu caso) o JavaScript roda no cliente (front-end).

Tem formas do JavaScript "comunicar" com o PHP. Vou exemplificar!

Mas, antes de mais nada, precisa se perguntar: a função PHP vai ser chamada já na renderização da página **e não depende de dados posteriores à renderização**?

---

Se sim, então você pode fazer direto na renderização:

<strike><sub>(o que acho má-prática, desnecessário, gambiarra, etc)</sub></strike>

```
<?php
    function minhaFuncaoPHP($param1, $param2){
        return ($param1+$param2);
    }

    $arg1 = 10;
    $arg2 = 7;
?>

<button type="button" onclick="funcaoJava()">Enviar</button>

<script>
    function funcaoJava(){
        let retornoPHP = '<?php echo minhaFuncaoPHP($arg1, $arg2); ?>';
        alert(retornoPHP);
    }
</script>
```

---

Se não, você terá que criar uma página que recebe uma requisição do JavaScript. Dessa forma, você pode transmitir dados para o PHP e retornar estes dados para o JavaScript.

Essa página em PHP é chamada de *WebService* (não precisa ser obrigatoriamente em PHP) e essa prática é, popularmente, conhecida como "*consumir um webservice*". Como se trata de JavaScript, dizemos "consumir um webservice com AJAX".

[image: Webservice]

<sub>(Fonte: [W3Schools - AJAX Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp))</sub>

Veja esse simples exemplo:

**1) Webservice em PHP: `funcao.php`**

```
<?php

function minhaFuncaoPHP($param1, $param2){
    return ($param1+$param2);
}

$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$resposta = minhaFuncaoPHP($dados['campo1'], $dados['campo2']);

echo json_encode($resposta);
```

Observe que essa página simplesmente: 1) carrega a função; 2) "parsea" os dados recebidos via AJAX; 3) chama a função que trata os dados; 4) "mostra" esses dados no formato do JSON.

**2) Cliente em HTML/JavaScript:**

```
<div>
    <label>
        Campo 1
        <input type="number" name="campo1">
    </label>
    <label>
        Campo 2
        <input type="number" name="campo2">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button">Enviar</button>
</div>
<script>
    let btn = document.querySelector('button[type=button]');
    btn.addEventListener(
        'click',
        function(){
            let data = {
                campo1: document.querySelector('input[name=campo1]').value,
                campo2: document.querySelector('input[name=campo2]').value
            }

            let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

            ajax.open('post', 'funcao.php');

            ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (
                    ajax.readyState == 4
                    && ajax.status >= 200
                    && ajax.status <= 400
                ) {
                    let respostaAjax = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

                    // Aqui os dados já foram tratados.
                    // Faça o que quiser com eles:
                    console.log(respostaAjax);
                }
            }

            ajax.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        false
    );
</script>
```

Só entenda o seguinte: isso é um exemplo mínimo! Não fique amarrado ao <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. Considere ler alguns artigos sobre o assunto e aprofunde-se nesse assunto de imensa utilidade.

> Leituras recomendadas:
>
> [Wikipédia - Web service](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)
>
> [W3Schools - AJAX Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)
>
> [SOen: Send JSON data to PHP using XMLHttpRequest w/o jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516019/send-json-data-to-php-using-xmlhttprequest-w-o-jquery)
>
> [PHP: `php://` - Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.php.php)
>
> [SOen: PHP “php://input” vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)